# how to run php Shell_exec script from website in android webview

Tags: php, android, android-webview

I have a php web application deployed in iis. We then have developed a webview which we use to load the php web application inside the webview.
on the php application we have a list of items and on click of one of them. it retrieves the file from the server into the tablet so that the file can be viewed using eDrawing app. Also im not sure if its possible to share files from the server into the tablet.

is it possible to run php shell_exec from php website in android webview. The website is loaded inside the webview. The reason i want to run it. is to open a file from the server using another application on tablet using intent.

something like below

```
$cmd ='#!/system/bin am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com';
shell_exec($cmd);
```

The script is inside the php web application that is deployed on iis.
how possible can this be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added more details to my question. Let me know if now makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. i ended up creating a virtual directory on iis under the application to map physical directory. In this way i can access the files using ip address port and the path which is the virtual directory.

now i can use  URLConnection and get the inputstream and share the file using Intent to targeted app on the tablet and open the file.